# Loading overlay doesn't work in Chrome, works in IE/Firefox

Tags: google-chrome, load, overlay, fade, freeze

I have a super simple loading overlay for my webpage:

```
<script type="text/javascript">  

    $(window).load(function(){  
          $("#loading").fadeOut();  
    })

</script>

...
...

<body>

    <div id="loading">
        <div id="loadingimage"><img src="../pictures/loading.gif"></div>
    </div>

...
...
</body>

#loading {
height:100%;
width:100%;
position:fixed;
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
filter:alpha(opacity = 80);
z-index:9999;
top:0;
bottom:0;
}
#loadingimage {
position:fixed;
height:100px;
width:100px;
top:50%; //center it
margin-top:-50px;
left:50%;
margin-left:-50px;
}
```

This works fine in Firefox/IE, the semi-transparent black overlay and loading image will fade out when the webpage loads, but in Chrome the loading div never fades out (the overlay + image), it just hangs there forever. The mouse icon is stuck in the "loading" icon as well. My website just has a bunch of images and text, no way it takes like an hour to load (which is how long I waited), so it has to be somethin wrong with the code.

Does Chrome not support "$(window).load(function()" or something?? This is the first time IE actually does something properly and Chrome doesn't... O_o

Answer (score 0):

Chrome enforces the 'same origin policy'. You might want to Google about that.Something about local file and whatnot.